# MPU6050 code explanation

Tags: arduino-uno, mpu6050, code-review

I'm new to arduino and electronics. I've been trying to use the MPU6050 with my arduino but I'm having difficulty understanding the code. I'm referring to the code put up on the arduino website (http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050#short). Is there any way I could get a line by line explanation of the code?

Comment: .... link? ....

Comment: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050#short

Comment: all my values are always zero, what mistake could I be making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added in a bunch of comments for you:

```
// MPU-6050 Short Example Sketch
// By Arduino User JohnChi
// August 17, 2014
// Public Domain
#include<Wire.h>
const int MPU_addr=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ; // declare accellerometer and gyro variables
void setup(){
  Wire.begin(); // initiate i2c system
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr); // be sure we talk to our MPU vs some other device
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true); // done talking over to MPU device, for the moment
  Serial.begin(9600); // initialize serial port to 9600 bps so you can see your debug messages in Arduino IDE via debug channel
}
void loop(){ // main program loop
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr); // get ready to talk to MPU again
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false); // done talking to MPU for the time being
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
  // all the fancy <<8| stuff is to bit shift the first 8 bits to
  // the left & combine it with the next 8 bits to form 16 bits
  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)    
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)
  // the above lines have gathered Accellerometer values for X, Y, Z
  //  as well as Gyroscope values for X, Y, Z

  Serial.print("AcX = "); Serial.print(AcX); // share accellerometer values over debug channel 
  Serial.print(" | AcY = "); Serial.print(AcY);
  Serial.print(" | AcZ = "); Serial.print(AcZ);
  Serial.print(" | Tmp = "); Serial.print(Tmp/340.00+36.53);  //equation for temperature in degrees C from datasheet
  Serial.print(" | GyX = "); Serial.print(GyX); // share gyroscope values over debug channel
  Serial.print(" | GyY = "); Serial.print(GyY);
  Serial.print(" | GyZ = "); Serial.println(GyZ);
  delay(333); // delay a bit to not overwhelm you the user/programmer as you view the results
}
```

Comment: Sure thing!  If this answer suits you, please remember to click the "answered" checkbox =)